# Intellj file shows as red "j" icon

Tags: intellij-idea

I was trying to use the eclipse from the intell j, so I basically chose the File - Export - project to Eclipse and then move those file to eclipse from intell j. Now, I want to go back to intell j since eclipse doesnt seems works for me. And then I see this red J icon in my class file in intell-j IDE.

[J icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2u8H.png)

Can anyone help me to get me back to intell j?
I been struggling with this for a while...

Comment: Looks like your files aren't located under sources root

Comment: How can I fix it? Can u plz help me?

Comment: Please attach screenshot with your project tree

Comment: You need to put these java files in a source root.
Please right-click an src folder, choose `Mark Directory as | Source Root`, then move these files under the src folder. See here for details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#configure-folders